# how to derive radius of annulus $r^2=\frac{4-\epsilon^2}{4+2\epsilon\sqrt{4-\epsilon^2}}$

Tags: general-topology

[image]
I have a questions concerning  the example in the above attached image. The example came from a text titled: Elements of Topology by Tej Bahadur Singh 
In the example, Sinh showed how $\mathbb{D}^{2}/\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{2}\\$
I don't understand how Singh got the expression for the radius of the annulus:
$r^2=\frac{4-\epsilon^2}{4+2\epsilon\sqrt{4-\epsilon^2}}$
Singh is using this expression to show the continuity of the homeomorphic mapping between the disk to the annulus.  I tried deriving it in terms of radius of concentric circles, and also using the method of cylindrical to spherical coordinate.  I was not having any success. I especially don't know where the term $4-\epsilon^2$ comes from. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use elementary plane geometry. The boundary $B'$ of the open ball $B(p;\varepsilon)$ is a circle of latitude in $\mathbb S^2$ at some height $s$ (i.e. points of $B'$ have the form $(x_0,x_1,s)$ with $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + s^2 = 1$). Consider the $x_1$-$x_2$-plane $P$. Then $S = \mathbb S^2 \cap P$ is the unit circle in this plane and $B' \cap S$ consists of the two points $(\pm \sqrt{1-s^2},s)$. Let $A = (\sqrt{1-s^2},s), N = (1,0), H = (0,s)$. We get a right triangle $(AHN)$. Drawing a picture is helpful. Using Pythagoras we get $\varepsilon^2 = (\sqrt{1-s^2})^2 + (1-s)^2$, thus $s = \frac{2-\varepsilon^2}{2}$ and $\sqrt{1-s^2} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sqrt{4 - \varepsilon^2}$.

Since we have $s = \dfrac{2r-1}{1 - 2r + 2r^2}$, we get
$$r = \dfrac{s+1+ \sqrt{1-s^2}}{2s}$$
which shows
$$r^2 = \dfrac{(s+1)(1 + \sqrt{1-s^2})}{2s^2} .$$
Inserting the above $s$ yields a formula expressing $r^2$ via $\varepsilon$, but is not the same as Singh's. However, it is irrelevant. Whatever the correct value for $r$ may be, it clear that the annulus $r <  \lVert x \rVert \le 1$ is an open neigborhhod of $\mathbb S^1 $ which is mapped by $f$ onto $B(p;\varepsilon) \subset U$.

Comment: after looking at your answer, I feel an extreme need to go reread my analytic geometry text for bed time reading.